# "PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented. This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance."

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

Essentially I'm ranking each column in the `df` dataframe and adding it to the `ranking` dataframe. I'm obviously not doing this very efficiently, and I'm wondering if someone can point me in the correct direction.

```
for x in range(1,num_sims+1):
    ranking[x] = df[x].rank(ascending=False, method='min')
```

The full error message is:

```
PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually
the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor
performance.  Consider using pd.concat instead.  To get a
de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`   ranking[x] =
df[x].rank(ascending=False, method='min')"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sample that reproduces the warning:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Sample `df`
np.random.seed(5)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 100, (4, 5000)))
df.columns = df.columns + 1

num_sims = len(df.columns)  # Placeholder for `num_sims`
ranking = pd.DataFrame()  # Placeholder for `ranking`

for x in range(1, num_sims + 1):
    ranking[x] = df[x].rank(ascending=False, method='min')
```

> PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead.  To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`
> ranking[x] = df[x].rank(ascending=False, method='min')

---

Fix using [`DataFrame.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) instead:

```
ranking = pd.DataFrame()  # Placeholder for `ranking`
ranking = pd.concat(
    [ranking, df[range(1, num_sims + 1)].rank(ascending=False, method='min')],
    axis=1
)
```

`output` without error:

```
   1     2     3     4     5     6     ...  4995  4996  4997  4998  4999  5000
0   2.0   2.0   3.0   1.0   4.0   1.0  ...   3.0   3.0   3.0   4.0   4.0   1.0
1   1.0   1.0   4.0   2.0   3.0   2.0  ...   4.0   1.0   2.0   3.0   1.0   3.0
2   3.0   4.0   1.0   4.0   1.0   4.0  ...   1.0   4.0   1.0   1.0   3.0   4.0
3   4.0   3.0   2.0   3.0   2.0   3.0  ...   2.0   2.0   3.0   2.0   2.0   2.0
```

*Naturally, if `ranking` is empty we can just create it directly from `df`:

```
ranking = df[range(1, num_sims + 1)].rank(ascending=False, method='min')
```

---

Sanity check that they produce the same results:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(5)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 100, (4, 5000)))
df.columns = df.columns + 1
ranking = pd.DataFrame()
num_sims = len(df.columns)

for x in range(1, num_sims + 1):
    ranking[x] = df[x].rank(ascending=False, method='min')

print(ranking.eq(pd.concat(
    [pd.DataFrame(),
     df[range(1, num_sims + 1)].rank(ascending=False, method='min')],
    axis=1
)).all(axis=None))  # True
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you. Any idea what I would do when using .map and slicing a dataframe?    for x in range(1, num_sims + 1):
     payouts[x] = ranking[x].map(prizes.set_index('Rank')['Payout'].to_dict())                                   for instance.